# How do you work with a function of a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, density-function, transform

[image]

I am struggling with parts b and c. How do you solve them?

Could you please give the solution?
[image]

Comment: (b) Try to find $F_X(x)$ and differentiate. (c) you just create random samples of $x$ and plot pdf, cdf etc and compare them to theoretical distribution.

Comment: @gunes Thanks - I tried this but am not sure I understand as it didn't work. Would you mind showing me the solution?

Comment: Why don’t you share yours and we can help you get unstuck.

Comment: thanks again @gunes
I added some things I tried as another pic in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

(b) Find $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(b/U^{1/a}\leq x)=P(U\geq b^a/x^a)$. Take it from here, find $F_X(x)$, and then differentiate wrt $x$ to find the PDF.

(c) Pick some $a,b$ of your choice, and using any programming language you like, create several uniform random variables, for each uniform random, calculate $X=b/U^{1/a}$ and get random $X$'s. Plot a normalized histogram, overlay the theoretical PDF and comment on it.